# Disable select element on specific radio button check

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to disable the "select" when "color1,color2 and color3" button is selected. And I wanted to enable it when the "color4" radio button was checked. I went to different resources and got confused how to put it in my codes.

here's my HTML:

```
    <br> <input type="radio" id="color1" name="color" value="orange" onchange="display()"  />
    <br> <input type="radio" id="color2" name="color" value="white" onchange="display()"  />
    <br> <input type="radio" id="color3" name="color" value="red" onchange="display()"  />

    // when checked, the select must be enable
    <br> <input type="radio" id="color4" name="color" value="other" onchange="display()"  />
    <select id="other_color" onchange="display()" />
             <option value="black">black</option>
             <option value="pink">pink</option>
             <option value="green">Green</option> </select>
    <div id="color_display" height="100px" width="100px"></div>
```

Now for my Js:

```
function display(){
    if(document.getElementById('color1').checked){
     document.getElementById('color_display').innerHTML = " Orange"; } 
    if(document.getElementById('color2').checked){
     document.getElementById('color_display').innerHTML = " White"; }
    if(document.getElementById('color3').checked){
     document.getElementById('color_display').innerHTML = " Red"; }

     if (document.getElementById('other_color').value == black') {
      document.getElementById('color_display').innerHTML = " Black"; }

     if (document.getElementById('other_color').value == 'pink') {
      document.getElementById('color_display').innerHTML = " Pink"; }

     if (document.getElementById('other_color').value == 'green') {
      document.getElementById('color_display').innerHTML = " Green";}
}
```

I haven't include the "color4" since it won't display anything, I want it to trigger to enable the selection.
Should I change or create another JS for checking? I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: "And I wanted to enable it when the right radio button was checked." -- what do you mean by by right radio button ? i. do you want show the same color in drop down as it is checked ? ii. And if "other" radio button is selected do you want to disable the drop down ?

Comment: oohh geez sorry, here want i wanted to say is like this is disable the "select" when "color1,color2 and color3" button is selected. And I wanted to enable it when the "color4" radio button was checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood. 
You can make the following changes in your JS code.

```
document.getElementById("other_color").disabled = true;//disabling the select tag initially;

function display() {
  if (document.getElementById('color1').checked) {
    document.getElementById('color_display').innerHTML = " Orange";
  }
  if (document.getElementById('color2').checked) {
    document.getElementById('color_display').innerHTML = " White";
  }
  if (document.getElementById('color3').checked) {
    document.getElementById('color_display').innerHTML = " Red";
  }

  if (document.getElementById('color4').checked) {
    document.getElementById('other_color').disabled = false;//enable the select tag when the radio 4th radio gets checked

    if (document.getElementById('other_color').value == 'black') {
      document.getElementById('color_display').innerHTML = " Black";
    }

    if (document.getElementById('other_color').value == 'pink') {
      document.getElementById('color_display').innerHTML = " Pink";
    }

    if (document.getElementById('other_color').value == 'green') {
      document.getElementById('color_display').innerHTML = " Green";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please change your js like that.

```
function display() {
        if (document.getElementById('color4').checked) {
            document.getElementById("other_color").disabled = true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("other_color").disabled = false;
        }
  }
```

Comment: if you want to show the selected color in drop down let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post and the information I deduce from your comment on your initial post and answers, I thing you are trying to achieve what I've replicated in the spinet below:

Instead of showing the select option by default, hide it so as to only show it when the *color4* radio button is select so as to make it more user friendly for an improved User Experience.

```js
var color = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="color"]'),
    displaySelectedColour = document.getElementById("color_display"),
    selectOption = document.getElementById("other_color");
  
for (var i in color) {
    color[i].onclick = function() {
        if (document.getElementById('color1').checked == true) {
            displaySelectedColour.style.display = "block";
            displaySelectedColour.innerText = "Orange";
            selectOption.style.display = "none";
        }
        if (document.getElementById('color2').checked == true) {
            displaySelectedColour.style.display = "block";
            displaySelectedColour.innerText = "White";
            selectOption.style.display = "none";
        }
        if (document.getElementById('color3').checked == true) {
            displaySelectedColour.style.display = "block";
            displaySelectedColour.innerText = "Red";
            selectOption.style.display = "none";
        }
        if (document.getElementById('color4').checked == true) {
            displaySelectedColour.style.display = "none";
            selectOption.style.display = "block";
        }
    };
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="color1" name="color" value="orange">
<br><input type="radio" id="color2" name="color" value="white">
<br><input type="radio" id="color3" name="color" value="red">
<br><input type="radio" id="color4" name="color" value="other">

<!-- Select disabled by default and enabled only on color4 radio button check -->
    <br>
    <select id="other_color" style="display: none;">
    <option disabled selected value>-- Select one --</option>
             <option>black</option>
             <option>pink</option>
             <option>green</option>
    </select>
    <div id="color_display" height="100px" width="100px"></div>
```